# Python nested for loop selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I'm creating two for loops (one nested in the other).

My code looks like this:

```
try:
    a = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("node")
    for links in a:
        links.click()
        for id in range(2, 41):
            my_id = "stree{}".format(id)
            browser.find_element_by_id(my_id).click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a[1]/img').click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input').click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click()
            sleep(5)
            # browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
except:
    a = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("node")
    for links in a:
        links.click()
        for id in range(2, 41):
            my_id = "stree{}".format(id)
            browser.find_element_by_id(my_id).click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a[1]/img').click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input').click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click()
            sleep(5)
            # browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

What the code is doing: 
It is going through two for loops and then going to a new page where it clicks on something. Then, I want the browser to go back to go through the for loops. The problem is that since the outer loop has to be executed first before the second loop could be executed, I face some issue while going back.

Two important questions:
1. Do I need to tell my browser to go back?
2. How can I execute the outercode first and then the code within?

The page looks like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdHZb.png)

The html for outer loop looks like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1DYK.png)

The html for inner loop (by clicking on this, I will go to the next page): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXjSJ.png)

How do I improve my code? Just to clarify: I want to go through all the files.

Edit: Someone asked for more clarification. In the photo of the page (attached), do you see folder icons? I want to click on them, that opens up all the file icons. I'm choosing those files by clicking on them, then clicking on the arrow in the page to put it into some box, and then clicking on "Accepting my selection" which takes me to the next page where I click on Excel, and that downloads my file. The "for-loop" is my attempt to go through all the files in those folders. Obviously, I have given a large explanation, but the point remains about the for-loop. The "class name - node" refers to folder icons and "for-id" refers to the file icons.

Comment: Try to simplify your code, to show us just the part where is the issue. Also, I do not really understand what is your intention. Please, rewrite your question to describe it better.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the end of the outer for loop, you could add a function that goes
   back to the starting page in order to click the next link

   OR
2. Instead of clicking the links, you could collect them and then use
   the outer loop to connect to these links. In other words, collect
   all links of the starting page with find_all and the make your
   browser connect to each one with the outer for loop. More specifically:

First, you create a browser instance (ABrowser could be Firefox() or anything else) and connect to the starting webpage as you already do:

```
browser = webdriver.ABrowser()
connection=browser.get(StartingPageURL)
```

Then you collect all links with the desired characteristics:

`a = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("node")`

And now you have a, which is a list of the links URLs. Instead of clicking a link, do the job and go back to the starting page, you can make your browser connect to the link URL, do the job and then connect to the next link URL etc. with a for loop

```
    for links in a:
        connection=browser.get(link) ## browser connect to the link URL
        for id in range(2, 41): 
            my_id = "stree{}".format(id)
            browser.find_element_by_id(my_id).click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a[1]/img').click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input').click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click()
            sleep(5)
```

Usually I prefer the second option

Comment: Could you give a little bit more of a explanation for the second suggestion? Thanks

Comment: how is it different than what I did?

Comment: With what you do you have to go back to the starting page every timw and click the next link. With the second option you just go to the next page. You understand that connecting to one page instead of two reduces significantly the time the program needs to run

Comment: but the problem is not the time, right? It is more about making it work. If the code doesn't run, how does it help me in reducing time? You are giving a solution for a problem that was not even asked.

Comment: No, both ways can make it work. I just point out the benefits of the second method

Comment: sorry - just one last question what is Abrowser?

Comment: Sorry about being unspecific about that. It is symbolically the browser you want to use. For example it could be `Firefox()`.

Comment: but the main issue is that there are two for loops? so in the second iteration it only recognizes the inner loop

Comment: I thought that the second loop is collecting the data once you are in the webpage. This is on you. I don't know how to collect them, since I don't know the webpage